# Is there any known result on twin primes in arithmetic progression?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, twin-primes

Is there any general conjecture / asymptote for twin primes in arithmetic progression in analytic number theory apart from Mikawa's paper?
This is the paper link https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tkbjm/1496161970

Comment: Please be fully specific about any reference or paper.  *Which* Mikawa paper?

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tkbjm/1496161970